# Hallar la Fecha Mínima en una lista de eventos

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

estoy corriendo este query:

```
SELECT   distinct Plataforma, SubPlataforma,  Job,  Schedule, Error,
Observaciones,  IdPersonaRegistra, strClic,
                         1 AS ContadorFallas, 
FORMAT(min(dtmFechaHoraFalla), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS fecha
FROM          tblProcesosFallidos
WHERE        (Plataforma = 1) AND strClic IS NOT NULL
group by Plataforma, SubPlataforma,  Job,  Schedule,  Error,
Observaciones,  IdPersonaRegistra, strClic
order by strClic DESC
```

Obtengo el resultado de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, salen repetidos los StrClic’s, lo que se requiere es que el # de clic solo se muestre una vez( ningun strClic repetido) y que se muestre la primera fecha donde ocurre. Alguna pista de como puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 0):

La cláusula `group by` funciona haciendo *grupos* en base a la lista de campos que le das. Es decir, va a sacar una fila de resultados por cada combinación que haya de los campos que se le dan, aplicando las funciones de agregación, como `count()`, `sum()`, `min()`, `max()` a todos los registros que forman parte de ese grupo.

En resumen, si quieres que strClic salga una sola vez, agrupa solamente por ese campo, así que la consulta básica sería algo como:

```
SELECT strClic, min(dtmFechaHoraFalla) FechaPrimeraFalla
  FROM tblProcesosFallidos
 WHERE (Plataforma = 1) 
   AND strClic IS NOT NULL
 group by strClic
 order by strClic DESC
```

Si necesitas incluir información de otros campos, entonces la única manera de que no se repita `strClic` es forzando al motor a elegir solamente uno de ellos, ya que de manera general, existe el riesgo que haya dos o más valores distintos en el campo y eso haría que aparezcan dos o más filas con el mismo `strClic` en el resultado, entonces, puedes mostrar el más pequeño que aparezca

```
SELECT   strClic
       , min(dtmFechaHoraFalla) FechaPrimeraFalla
       , min(Plataforma) PrimeraPlataforma
       , min(SubPlataforma) PrimeraSubPlataforma
       , etcétera
  FROM tblProcesosFallidos
 WHERE (Plataforma = 1) 
   AND strClic IS NOT NULL
 group by strClic
 order by strClic DESC
```

En resumen: Al momento que incluyas un segundo campo en la cláusula `group by` no podrás garantizar que haya una sola fila para cada `strClic`.

Generalizando la idea, supongamos estos datos:

```
Puesto     | Departamento  |  Salario | Empleado
-------------------------------------------------
Jefe       | Ventas        | 100      | Juan Pérez
Secretaria | Ventas        | 100      | María Godinez
Jefe       | Compras       | 200      | José Rodríguez
Secretaria | Compras       | 150      | Inés Hernández
Secretaria | Compras       | 100      | Miriam Pérez
```

Si agrupas solo por `Puesto`, digamos:

```
select Puesto, sum(Salario) from Empleado group by Puesto
```

Vas a obtener solo dos registros:

```
Puesto      | Suma
----------------------
Jefe        | 300
Secretaria  | 350
```

De manera similar si agrupas por `Departamento`, pero en el momento que agrupas por `puesto` y `departamento`, vas a obtener 4 registros, pues cada combinación de puesto y departamento son un grupo

```
select Puesto, sum(Salario) from Empleado group by Puesto
```

Va a devolver:

```
Puesto      | Departamento | Suma
----------------------------------
Jefe        | Ventas       | 100
Jefe        | Compras      | 100
Secretaria  | Ventas       | 200
Secretaria  | Compras      | 250
```